# parse JSON and saving data to the realm is it possible?

Tags: json, swift, realm

```
struct NewsModel: Codable{

    let id: Int?
    let title, newsModelDescription: String?
    let sourceID, version: String?
    let publishedAt: Int
    let readablePublishedAt: String?
    let updatedAt: Int
    let readableUpdatedAt: String
    let images: Images
    let embedTypes: String?
    let typeAttributes: TypeAttributes
    let type: String?
    let source: String?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title
        case newsModelDescription
        case sourceID
        case version, publishedAt, readablePublishedAt, updatedAt, readableUpdatedAt, embedTypes, images,typeAttributes, type, source
    }
}

// MARK: - Images
struct Images: Codable {
    let square140: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case square140 = "square_140"
    }
}

struct TypeAttributes: Codable {
    let imageLarge: String
}
```

This is my Model. I can successfully parse them and show them on UITableViewCell but I am unable to save them to the realm because these are struct. For save to realm I need to convert them to class and Realm object. But how I convert them to nested class. I want to use the same model to parse and saving data to the realm is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just make NewsModel a Realm object? Or. make it a swift class and add a function `func saveToRealm` which when called creates a Realm object and maps the properties to mananaged realm properties and saves? Or. Just make it a realm object that's codable. Or. Add an extension and make it codable. There's a ton of options, what have you tried?

Comment: @Jay thanks for your suggestion. Would you kindly give me a example?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably 100 different solutions. One option is to just make the object a Realm object that's conforms to the codable protocol. Something like this (not tested: so more of a conceptual solution)

```
class NewsModel: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var _id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var news = ""

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case _id
        case title
        case news
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self._id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: ._id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.logo = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .news)
    }
```

or change the model in the question to a class and add a function to save a realm object with the data. Again, not tested so this is just conceptual.

```
class RealmNewsModel: Object {
   @objc dynamic var _id = ""
   @objc dynamic var title = ""
   @objc dynamic var news = ""
}

class NewsModel, Codable {
   let _id: String?
   let title: String?
   let news: String?

   func saveToRealm {
      let news = RealmNewsModel()
      news._id = self._id
      news.title = self.title
      news.news = self.news
      try! realm.write {
          realm.add(news)
      }
```